# Representing a monomial reflection group in Sage.

Tags: group-theory, sagemath

I can represent some groups in Sage. But cannot represent $G(m,p,q)$. How would I represent the group $G(m,p,q)$ in sage so that I can operate on it?

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers, let $C_m$ be the cyclic group of order
> $m$ and $B = C_m\times\dots\times C_m$ be the direct product of $n$ copies of $C_m$.
> For each divisor $p$ of $m$ define the group $A(m, p, n)$ by
> $$
> A(m, p, n) 
> = 
> \left\{\ (\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots , \theta_n) \in B 
> \ \Big|\  
> (\theta_1\theta_2\dots\theta_n)^{m/p} = 1\ 
> \right\}
> \ .
> $$
> It follows that $A(m, p, n)$ is a subgroup of index $p$ in $B$ and the symmetric group $\operatorname{Sym}(n)$ acts naturally on
> $A(m, p, n)$
> by permuting the coordinates.
> $G(m, p, n)$ is defined to be the semidirect product of $A(m, p, n)$ by $\operatorname{Sym}(n)$. It follows that $G(m, p, n)$ is a normal subgroup of index $p$ in
> the wreath product $C_m ≀ \operatorname{Sym}(n)$ and thus has order $m^n\;n!/p$.
> It is well known that these groups can be realized as finite subgroups
> of $GL_n(\Bbb C)$, specifically as $n \times n$ matrices with exactly one non-zero entry, which is a complex $m$-th root of unity, in each row and column such that the product of the entries is a complex $(m/p)$th root of unity.
> Thus the groups $G(m, p, n)$ are sometimes referred to as monomial
> reflection groups.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Could you type from the picture to the problem description? Although this may take some time, but if you do, I will appreciate this!

Comment: I edited in the typed-out version of the image.

Comment: Also asked on https://ask.sagemath.org/question/61096/how-do-i-represent-monomial-reflection-groups/

Comment: Please give explicit references. Which is the source (appearing in the image)? Which is a reference for the well known property of such group to realize them inside linear groups? And what did you try? Which values for $m,p,n$ are of interest? (...since implementing this in sage needs explicit values for these variables.)